# Get the HWND from a GraphicsCaptureItem picked by a GraphicsCapturePicker

Tags: c#, uwp

I capture a window/the full screen with a GraphicsCapturePicker in order to record it, but if the captured window is minimised, my program don't know how to manage it so I want to maximize it using its HWND.

```cs
public async Task<GraphicsCaptureItem> PickItemToRecordAsync()
{
     var picker = new GraphicsCapturePicker();
     GraphicsCaptureItem item = await picker.PickSingleItemAsync();

     return item;
}
```

The link from documentation which I have read already: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.graphicscaptureitem

Comment: you can include your comment in the question @Iulian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my program don't know how to manage it so I want to maximize it using its HWND.

Currently, [`GraphicsCapturePicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.graphicscapturepicker) does not provide api to maximize capture item. If we want to capture full screen, we need `maximize` capture window manually.